# Grouping records with the same name, without explicitly naming each one in an xml function

Tags: xml, function

Firstly please accept my apologies. I have no previous experience with XML. I have been given some software that has an XML configuration file, the software takes data and looks for items that match.

**The problem: Users are able to manually match records, but there is nothing in place to stop them matching records where the names don't match.**

The syntax that allows a user to manually match a record is this:

```
<action name="ACCEPT">    
    <rules>     
        <rule>
            <![CDATA[${AtLeastOneOfEach} and (abs(${TotalNetAmount}) <= decimalLimit("NetAmountLimit"))]]>
        </rule>     
    </rules>  
</action>
```

To look at correcting this issue I have loaded some sample data into a test environment where one match contains a client with the name "John". I have then created a function like this:

```
<function>
    <name>AllAreJohn</name>
    <description>match contains all clients called John</description>
    <rule>
        <![CDATA[(all have Client_Name="John") ]]>
    </rule>
</function>
```

Using this function I have then edited the manual action to as follows:

```
<action name="ACCEPT">    
    <rules>     
        <rule>
            <![CDATA[${AllAreJohn} and (abs(${TotalNetAmount}) <= decimalLimit("NetAmountLimit"))]]>
        </rule>     
    </rules>  
</action>
```

Working through my example, the above seems to work - where the client name is "John" (and the other criteria are fulfilled).

**The question: Is there a way to re-write the XML function so that I don't have to declare the client name each time. I basically want the function to ensure that a group can only be formed when all the client names are the same.**

Hope this makes sense. Many thanks for looking and in advance for any help you may be able to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-using some code already contained in the configuration I came up with the below, this achieves what I was originally hoping to do do.

```
<function>
<name>AllSameName</name>
<description>match contains all of the same client name</description>
<rule>
<![CDATA[(same Client_Name)]]>
</rule>
</function>
```